# Why 'I am not' used here?

Tags: sentence-construction

> I am no longer try to convince people I am important while secretly
>   fearing I am not.

What is the role of 'I am not' in this term? Why didn't used 'that's not' instead?

Comment: He used to try to convince people that he was important. At that time he feared that he was not important. Why do you think he should call himself _that_?

Comment: @Lambie But it is - did you read it all?

Comment: Ok, I see it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have quoted is not grammatical: you mean *I no longer try*, or possibly *I am no longer trying*.

When you end a clause with *not* it is usually understood to be implicitly followed by something that came earlier in the sentence.  So *I am not* is means  *I am not important*.

"That's not" would not make sense here, because the thing whose importance is being talked about is "I", not some "that".

Comment: (So we go, rowing our boats along the editing stream. :))